# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error de baja resolución de imágenes en la API de Mercado Libre?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, mercadolibre

Estoy desarrollando una E-commerce para mi portfolio pero al hacer fetch sobre la API me arroja imágenes en baja calidad.

[image: ¿Alguien sabe si tiene solución?]